# Reading from an file with comma as delimiter and storing the data into an object and then saving the data into list

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, delimiter

```java
import java.util.*;

public class ReadFile {
  public static class Em implements Comparable<Em> {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double Salary;
 
    public int getId() {
      return id;
    }

    // same get methods for sal and name here

    public Em(int id, String name, double e) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.sal = sal;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException {
    String record;
    List<Em> eL = new ArrayList<Em>();
    BufferedReader be = new BufferedReader(new File("Location"));
    List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
      while ((record = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] rows = record.spilt(",");
        Em e = null;
        int a = Integer.parseInt(rows[0]);
        String b = rows[1];
        double c = Double.parseDouble(rows[2]);
        eL.add(new Em(a, b, c);
        arlist.add(Arrays.toString(rows));

        System.out.println(eL.toString);
      }
    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Please Note:
Location of file is correct.
Any typo might be there.

The file contains data as follows:

```
1,Duke,13000
2,Jake,14000
...
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[test.ReadFile$Em@7852e922]
[test.ReadFile$Em@7852e922,test.ReadFile$Em@4e25154f]
```

I need help

1. Am I doing it correctly
2. Any alternate program will help

Future:
I have to write emp details who has maximum salary into another file

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is good (if we forget the typos which, I assume, are not present in your code). The reason your program is outputting `[test.ReadFile$Em@7852e922] [test.ReadFile$Em@7852e922,test.ReadFile$Em@4e25154f]` is because of the way you are trying to print it. What you see is the memory adress of your ArrayList, not the content. To print the content of your ArrayList, you need to use a ***for loop*** that goes through the entire content of your ArrayList index by index and then prints its content. Here's a quick example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < eL.length(); i++) {
  System.out.println(eL.get(i).getA)
  System.out.println(eL.get(i).getB)
  System.out.println(eL.get(i).getC)
}
```

This way of doing it gets the `Em` object for every index in the `El` ArrayList, and then prints its A, B and C value using a `get` command that you can easily add to your `Em` Class.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `toString()` method in `Em` class.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.id + " " + this.name + " " + this.salary;
}
```